# Git Repo Auto-commit and Push

Tags: git, commit, post-commit, post-commit-hook, git-bare

I have a scenario where I have a repo where users access the files directly, they don't know git exists, and make changes to what are essentially text files.

I have that repo cloned. So when a commit is made, the changes are pushed to the cloned repo using the post-commit hook.

Now, I have the cloned repo as a bare repo. But, what I would like to do at this point is have a script run each time a push is made. That script would read the content of the file(s) that were just pushed. Is that treated as a commit? Can I again use the post-commit hook?

Can that be done on a bare repo? Since there is no working directory? I'm don't see how I could "read" the file if the repo is bare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the hook. However, you must use lower level git command to retrieve the commit tree and files from a bare repo. E.g.  http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-2.html

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful.
So when you say that I can use the hook, do you mean the post-commit hook on the bare repo? The push will actually do a commit?

And then do I need to do more than just a commit to get the object hash created? Like this $ git hash-object -w test.txt.

Comment: I'm just not sure how I can then read the file from the bare repo. Do I always have to make it an object?