# Azure Websites Dropbox Sync from API

Tags: azure

I have been looking through the C# and Rest API's for the Microsoft Azure web sites but I cannot find a way of executing the drop box sync command that can be done through the azure portal. Is this possible from an API that any one knows of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup Continuous Deployment with DropBox on Windows Azure Website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693707/setup-continuous-deployment-with-dropbox-on-windows-azure-website)

Comment: No, I don't want a continuous deployment. I don't want to give developers access to the azure portal but instead allow them to deploy code into drop box and then using a remote panel in our systems call the sync command.

Comment: In any case, the answer is no at least for now. You would need to go to the portal and do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is support for deploying a WebDeploy file to a Website using PowerShell, so there must be a corresponding API for it.

If you download the publish settings for the website, you'll se that it has a PublishUrl which is the WebDeploy endpoint for the server, along with a msdeploySite, which is your unique site on the server. A WepDeploy file is nothing more than a fancy zip (AFAIK), so by digging into this it should be possible to come up with something which can talk to the webdeploy endpoint and thereby publish.

I don't think that API is something Microsoft publishes though, so you might have to dig deep.